# How to setup a data file in MiniZinc?

Tags: minizinc

In Config tab Additional arguments I put:
C:\data\j.dzn
Which cryptically replies:
Error: cannot handle file extension dzn".
Usage: mzn2fzn [] [-I ] .mzn [.dzn ...]

Comment: Er, what? Is this a question at all, let alone an on-topic, researched *programming* question?

Comment: Jim, this kind of very specific question about errors belong to either MiniZinc forum (https://www.minizinc.org/forum/ ) or MiniZincIDE issues ( https://github.com/MiniZinc/MiniZincIDE/issues ).

Comment: No doubt you have much more experience with stackoverflow than I and I respect your input but after your advice I checked the help and don't find support for your supposition, nor QPaysTaxes. For my curiosity could you point me to a help section that clarifies this issue?